# Sending (simple) data streams from GATT client to server

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a PCB which is using a TI Bluetooth LE chip (CC2541). I'm hoping to send some simple weather data from the client (e.g., phone) to the server (CC2541) infrequently (once a day/week). Will a custom profile need to be implemented for this? Could an established profile be modified to handle the data, e.g., the Proximity Profile but with larger attributes?

If every type of data needs a profile, it seems rather clumsy. What is the canonical approach to sending/handling simple data streams?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this [link](https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/profiles/Pages/ProfilesHome.aspx), you can see the full list of *Bluetooth* *SIG* profiles. The services and characteristics in these profiles have 16 bit UUIDs that are defined by *SIG*. For inter-operability between vendors, it is recommended to use SIG defined profiles. For example let's think about a mobile application developer who is developing an app that collects glucose level from medical devices. If [Glucose profile](https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/profiles/Pages/ProfileViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.profile.glucose.xml) were not defined by *Bluetooth SIG*, the developer would have to think about each vendor's implementation. Bluetooth SIG defined profiles are kind of specifications for the purpose of inter-operability. The number of *Bluetooth SIG* defined profiles have been increased and the list is updated since Bluetooth Version 4.

In your case, you have to implement your own custom profile. All the custom services and characteristic should have 128 bit UUIDs. I would suggest to make some readings from Bluetooth SIG website. [Smart Starter Kit](https://developer.bluetooth.org/Pages/smart-starter-kit.aspx) and [Application Accelerator Kit](https://www.bluetooth.com/develop-with-bluetooth/developer-resources-and-tools/application-accelerator) contain really good documentation about custom profiles and source code samples.

Comment: I see. Will I need to implement my own custom profile or custom service? Isn't it the case that profiles can be optional and that services don't need to be encapsulated inside them? I heard that Android can cope even without a profile.

Comment: In those documents you will read what a profile is and the hierarchical structure between profile, services, characteristics and descriptors. It goes like that profile>service>characteristic>descriptor. A profile have at least one or more services. A service has at least one or more characteristics. A characteristic has at least one or more descriptors.

Comment: You need to have one custom profile and this profile will have custom weather service. Custom weather service will have your custom characteristics. In Bluetooth LE, you don't discover profiles, but you discover characteristic and services. Grouping services as profiles is logical. Thus, creating services and characteristics means you already created your profile.